# A movie with a time machine that is being used to stop a crime

Tags: identify-this-movie, time-travel

It's a Hollywood movie.I saw it five or six years ago, and now I don't remember its name or cast.

The plot was something like this: there is a department with a time machine. They use this machine to go back in time and stop a crime before it happens, as they knew where the crime scene was. They send their man (a cop) to the crime scene just before the time of the crime and stop it to from happening. There's a limited time frame, and as soon as the time frame is over, he automatically goes back to the place/time where he started.

I remember one scene in which he had been sent to a kind of forest, and there was a group of bad guys with a female hostage, and the back office team could see what was going on in there.

One more thing: the movie is not *Minority Report*, *Source Code*, or *Timecop*. Please help me with this.

Comment: Sounds exactly like Time Cop to me. How did the individual get back after the crime was stopped?

Comment: There's also Deja Vu, but I think they have limited abilities there.

Comment: they send them back with a limited time lap and as soon as the lap gets over they automatically get back to the place from where they started.

Comment: Is the hero a cop? Do they send him to multiple, ordinary crime scenes? Cause otherwise 12 Monkeys could fit the bill too... Be as descriptive as possible, it'll narrow it down.

Comment: i remember on of the scenes in which he had been sent to a place kind of forest and there was a group of bad guys with a female hostage and the hero was a cop and the back office team could see what is going on in there.

Comment: What year was it from, approximately? (I assume it was in English)

Comment: Except for the comment "automatically get back", I thought of the TV series "7 Days", but that required the agent to get back into his machine, and sometimes (oh-h, the drama!) repair it first in the Nick! of! Time!

Comment: i watched that movie 5-6 years ago, but i dont remember the year of the movie, and it was hollywood movie.

Comment: OK, added it all in.

Comment: Maybe Freejack or Slipstream? There's also a pretty comprehensive list of Time Travel movies on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Time_travel_films

Comment: Do you remember any actors or roughly when it was made? 80s? 90s?

Comment: There have been some similar tv shows, like Crime Traveller and Time Trax.

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking for a movie that has the same details... I was pretty sure it had Denzel Washington so I checked his list of works. Are you thinking of the movie "[Deja Vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_Vu_%282006_film%29)"?

IMDB Description:

> A ferry filled with crewmen from the USS Nimitz and their families was blown up in New Orleans on Mardi Gras. BATF Doug Carlin is brought in to assist in the massive investigation, and gets attached to an experimental FBI surveillance unit, one that uses spacefolding technology to directly look back a little over four days into the past. While tracking down the bomber, Carlin gets an idea in his head: could they use the device to actually travel back in time and not only prevent the bombing but also the murder of a local woman whose truck was used in the bombing?